# Postgress: custom upsert (stored proc?) when inserting multiple rows at once?

Tags: postgresql

There's a table:

```
create table mytab(
  r char(38) not null,
  h char(2),
  p bytea not null,
  primary key (r,h)
)
```

I'm inserting hundreds of rows at once, like this:

```
insert into mytab (r, h, p) values 
('val_r', 'a0', 'pr_1'), ('r1', 'a1', 'p1')......
```

I need to replace the regular `insert` with a "smart" one:

1. if there're no such keys `(r,h)` then insert the row
2. if the keys exist and the value (`p`) is the same as new then do nothing
3. if the keys exist but the value is different - throw an error for this particular row only, somehow let the app know that this particular row has error - and continue with other rows

I've read about `insert ... on conflict do update/nothing` but it looks like it's not applicable esp. because of rule 3, in docs I found nothing like "do fail".

So, how can I do it, inserting many rows at once? Maybe something like stored procedure, but how?

PgSQL 15, psycopg2. Using `insert` one row at a time is not an option due to performance penalty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a trigger for the table.

```sql
create or replace function before_insert_on_mytab()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    select *
    from mytab
    where r = new.r and h = new.h
    into rec;
    if rec is not null then
        if rec.p <> new.p then
            -- notice
            raise notice '%', new;
            -- notify
            perform pg_notify('mytab_log', new::text);
            -- log table
            insert into mytab_errors values
            (new.r, new.h, new.p);
        end if;
        return null;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;
```

The trigger function filters inserted rows and reports incorrect ones as a notice, or channel notification, or in a special table (your choice).

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/1FAD6xkN)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do it one row at a time, but you can still use `ON CONFLICT`. Use two queries, one to insert all the value and a second to find the values that failed your condition. You can even put them into a single statement using a CTE:

```
WITH input(r, h, p) AS (VALUES
  ('val_r'::char(38), 'a0'::char(2), 'pr_1'::bytea),
  ('r1', 'a1', 'oops this is different'),
  ('new', 'kx', 'anything')
),
inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO mytab (r, h, p)
  SELECT * FROM input
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
  RETURNING *
)
SELECT r, h, mytab.p, input.p AS p_attempted
FROM input
JOIN mytab USING (r, h)
WHERE input.p <> mytab.p;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Crd1Pht6))</sup>

If you don't need to distinguish the already-existing rows between having the same or a different value, you can also just get the rows that were not inserted using

```
…
TABLE input
EXCEPT
TABLE inserted;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-wMf4Q2R))</sup>

Comment: The approach is interesting, but  I'm afraid `join` or `except` will be unacceptably slow on a really big table (hundreds of million rows), this is why I accepted another answer. Thank you anyway and +1.

Comment: @Putnik How many rows are you inserting? The join should handle that just fine, no matter how many rows there are in `mytab`.  Notice that the trigger in klin's answer does query `mytab` for every single inserted row as well, so that's just as slow (or probably even slower) than a single `join` query.

Comment: Atm I'm playing with batch size from 256 to 4k, total table size will be 2+ mlrd rows and most likely growing. Yes, there's select for each row but index will be used.

Comment: @Putnik The `join` certainly will also use the index

Answer (score -1):

Maybe create a procedure with a **out** parameter and use **cursor** to select rows from the table and loop through each row. Check within the table mytab if there exists any record with r, h like this.

```
DECLARE
existing_count bigint DEFAULT 0;
r_value char(38);
h_value char(2);
p_value bytea;
v_query text;
c1 CURSOR for SELECT r,h,p FROM temp_table;
BEGIN
OPEN c1;
FETCH c1 INTO r_value, h_value, p_value;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;  
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO existing_count FROM mytab WHERE r = r_value AND h = h_value AND p <> p_value;
IF existing_count > 0 THEN
  CONCAT(COALESCE(p_out, ''), E'\n Failed for r = ', r_value, ' , h = ', h_value, ' and p = ', p_value);
END IF;
v_query := CONCAT('INSERT INTO mytab (r,h,p) VALUES (',r_value,',',h_value,',', p_value,') ON CONFLICT (r,h) DO NOTHING;');
EXECUTE v_query;
CLOSE c1;
END;
```

This is the cursor code only not the procedure.
Here I have used p_out which will be the **out** parameter for the stored procedure.
Initially insert all records in the temp_table.
upon calling the procedure the **out** parameter will provide the output with the details of failing rows on each line.

Comment: This code doesn't do what was asked for. It's not clear to me why you opened the gates to SQL injection either.